# Check if tr with specific id is last in a table

Tags: jquery

Check if tr with specific id is last in a table

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
    smthing
</tr>   
<tr id="test1" class=""tableRows>
    smthing
</tr>
<tr id="test2" class=""tableRows>
    smthing
</tr>
</table>
```

i want to do something like

```
var count=1

$("tr#test<?=count?>").fadeOut("slow")

count--

if($("#table tbody tr.tableRows:last"))
alert("empty - tr with class tableRows")
```

Comment: Where does PHP come into it at all?

Comment: mentioned it coz was passing the id count through php <?=count?>

Comment: But that's not valid PHP, and you appear to have created the variable in Javascript anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var $trs    = $('#table tr');
var is_last = $trs.index($('#' + id)) == $trs.length - 1;
```

where `id` is the ID of the `<tr>` in question. The [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) gives you the zero based index of the element in question within the `$trs` (which is all the rows).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4F7Ak/